# Distance and Duration is not being displayed in Text - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, expo

I am having an issue of displaying Distance and Duration  despite getting correct data when console log.

array of data

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    contacts: {
      phone: "123-456-7890",
      whatsapp: "254710306878",
      email: "johndoe@example.com"
    },
    location: {
      name: "Mombasa, town, Kenya",
      Latitude: "-0.2060724",
      Longitude: "35.8493085"
    },
    transporter: {
      name: "Lorry",
      category: "Tonnage"
    },
    image: "https://links.papareact.com/3pn",
    price: 150 
  },
];
```

Distance and Duration calculation

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to calculate the distance between two coordinates
    const calculateDistance = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) => {
      const toRad = (value) => (value * Math.PI) / 180;
      const R = 6371; // Earth's radius in km
      const dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1);
      const dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);
      const a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
      const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
      const distanceT = R * c;
      return distanceT;
    };

   // Calculate the distance and duration for each item in the data array and update the data with the calculated values
   const updatedData = data.map((item) => {
    const distanceT = calculateDistance(
      originLocation.latitude,
      originLocation.longitude,
      parseFloat(item.location.Latitude),
      parseFloat(item.location.Longitude)
    );
    console.log(`Distance between origin and ${item.location.name}: ${distanceT} km`);
    return {
      ...item,
      distanceT: distanceT.toFixed(2) + ' km', // Round the distance to 2 decimal places and add 'km' suffix
    };
  });

  // Fetch distance and duration from Google Maps API
  const originCoordinates = `${originLocation.latitude},${originLocation.longitude}`;
  const destinationCoordinates = `${destinationLocation.latitude},${destinationLocation.longitude}`;

  fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=${originCoordinates}&destinations=${destinationCoordinates}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.status === 'OK' && data.rows[0] && data.rows[0].elements[0] && data.rows[0].elements[0].distance && data.rows[0].elements[0].duration) {
        setDistance(data.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
        setDuration(data.rows[0].elements[0].duration);
        setIsFetching(false);

        // Set the duration value in the updatedData array
        const updatedDataWithDuration = updatedData.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          duration: data.rows[0].elements[0].duration,
        }));

        // Now set the updated data with distance and duration
        setData(updatedDataWithDuration);
      } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid response data from Google Maps API');
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      setIsFetching(false);
    });
}, [originLocation, destinationLocation]);

  ``

Logs
```

LOG  Distance between origin and Mombasa, town, Kenya: 32.775468102479756 km
LOG  Distance between origin and Nakuru, city, Kenya: 6.818252171669251 km
LOG  Distance between origin and Nakuru West, administrative, Kenya: 10.180950124064083 km
LOG  Distance between origin and Barnabas Highway Market, marketplace, Gilgil, Kenya: 3.856947535126265 km
LOG  Distance between origin and Nairobi, city, Kenya: 134.1152987788935 km

```
display of data
```

return (
<SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white flex-1` }>

{isFetching ? (
Loading...
) : (
<>
Distance: {distance.text}
Duration: {duration.text}

```
      {/* Displaying Distance and Duration for each item in the data array */}
      {data.map((item) => (
      <View key={item.id} style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text>
          Name: {item.firstName} {item.lastName}
        </Text>
        <Text>Contacts: Phone: {item.contacts.phone}, Email: {item.contacts.email}</Text>
        <Text>Distance: {item.distanceT}</Text>
                  
        <Text>Duration: {item.duration ? item.duration.text : 'N/A'}</Text>
      </View>
    ))}
    </>
  )}
</View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

);

```
I guess calculated distance and duration to item is not correctly map so that it can be loop in view

I am expecting to pass or display distance and duration to loop view

Kindly help
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=${originCoordinates}&destinations=${destinationCoordinates}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}`)
Actually the problem is when we fetch the destination.description it gets null change it to destination.desciption because Google api developer just put the wrong variable name there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).